# Setting conversations on screen

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I want to have NPC conversations be displayed on screen like the example picture below, but I am not sure how to go about doing this. How can I get the text to be displayed on the screen like in the picture below? Any tips or advice pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.[image: example]